# I created a custom Carousel it's working but I want it to come from both ways

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently Carousel is just sliding in one way and it is not even draggable or touchable for mobile screen

I want the Carousel to work in a 360 mode like a loop it keeps loading the slides instead all goes out and carousel came back to start again It should just keep going infinite

I want on hover the slides stop and can be draggable and touchable for responsive mobile

please check the code

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item");
const numVisibleSlides = 4;
const gap = 10; // Space between slides
const totalSlides = items.length;
let currentIndex = 0;

// Calculate the total width of visible slides
const slideWidth = (85 - (numVisibleSlides - 1) * gap) / numVisibleSlides;

// Initialize pagination buttons
const pagination = document.querySelector(".pagination");
items.forEach((_, index) => {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.classList.add("pagination-button");
  button.addEventListener("click", () => goToSlide(index));
  pagination.appendChild(button);
});

// Highlight the active pagination button
function updatePagination() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-button");
  buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      button.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      button.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
}

// Go to a specific slide
function goToSlide(index) {
  currentIndex = index;
  updateCarousel();
  updatePagination();
}

// Update the carousel's position
function updateCarousel() {
  const translateX = -currentIndex * (slideWidth + gap);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}%)`;
}

// Initialize the carousel
updateCarousel();
updatePagination();

// Auto play (remove/comment this code if you don't want auto play)
const autoPlayInterval = 3000; // Change interval as needed
let autoPlayTimer;

function startAutoPlay() {
  autoPlayTimer = setInterval(() => {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % (totalSlides + numVisibleSlides);
    if (currentIndex >= totalSlides) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    updateCarousel();
    updatePagination();
  }, autoPlayInterval);
}

function stopAutoPlay() {
  clearInterval(autoPlayTimer);
}

startAutoPlay();
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.carousel-item {
  flex: 0 0 calc(24% - 10px);
  min-width: calc(24% - 10px);
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.pagination button {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination button.active {
  background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you could do is change the order of the elements after the animation is done.

Comment: There are libraries online for this, that are free to use: check https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick/